# Get all children models from a parent class - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I get all the children models from a parent class?
As an example I have :

```
class Device(PolymorphicModel):
   .....

class Mobile(Device): 
   .....

class Computer(Device):
   .....
```

So I want to get from the Device model its all descendants : Mobile, Computer as classes not as instances.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the *direct* subclasses with the [**`class.__subclasses__()`** <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#class.__subclasses__) method:

```
>>> Device.__subclasses__()
[<class 'Mobile'>, <class 'Computer'>]
```

It is however possible that these also have subclasses. We can develop an algorithm that each time obtains the next generation, and keeps doing this until no new subclasses are found, like:

```
def get_descendants(klass):
    gen = { klass }
    desc = set()
    while gen:
        gen = { skls for kls in gen for skls in kls.__subclasses__() }
        desc.update(gen)
    return desc
```

or with a variable number of parameters:

```
def get_descendants(*klass):
    gen = { *klass }
    desc = set()
    while gen:
        gen = { skls for kls in gen for skls in kls.__subclasses__() }
        desc.update(gen)
    return desc
```

this will return a `set()` containing all descendants (both direct and indirect).