# GenericForeignKey in Grappelli admin: filter content_type to display only relevant models

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-grappelli

With [related lookups](https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.io/en/autocomplete/customization.html#related-lookups), I can easily get access to all the models I have to have a generic foreign key. Obviously, this is not what I want to do. I want to restrict it to just a sub set of the models I have -- specifically all the inherit from the abstract model `Registry`.

My models look like thus:

```
class Registry(models.Model):
    """A base registry class."""

    number = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    when = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=1024, default='', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        """The meta class."""

        abstract = True

    […]


class Revision(models.Model):
    """A revision model."""

    when = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    identification = models.BigIntegerField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    parent = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    […]


class Document(Registry):

    […]

class Drawing(Registry):

    […]
```

So that each `Registry` derived instances can have many different revisions.

And the relevant admin:

```
class RevisionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Revision administration definition."""

    fieldsets = [
        ('Revision', {
            'fields': [
                'when',
                'identification',
            ]
        }),
        ('Registry', {
            'classes': ('grp-collapse grp-open',),
            'fields': ('content_type', 'object_id', )
        }),
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [**`limit_choices_to`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to). Since you want to limit the choices to the *descendants*, we will need to write some extra logic to calculate these first:

We can for example first calculate all the subclasses with [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853645/67579):

> ```
> def get_descendants(klass):
>     gen = { klass }
>     desc = set()
>     while gen:
>         gen = { skls for kls in gen for skls in kls.__subclasses__() }
>         desc.update(gen)
>     return desc
> ```

Now we can define a callable to obtain the primary keys of the `ContentType`s that are subclasses of a class, in this case `Registry`:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

def filter_qs():
    if not hasattr(filter_qs_registry, '_q'):
        models = get_descendants(Registry)
        pks = [v.pk for v in ContentType.objects.get_for_models(*models).values()]
        filter_qs_registry._q = Q(pk__in=pks)
    return filter_qs_registry._q
```

In the `ForeignKey` to the `ContentType`, we can then use the `limited_choices_to` field:

```
class Revision(models.Model):
    """A revision model."""
    when = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    identification = models.BigIntegerField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to=filter_qs_registry,
        related_name='+'
    )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    parent = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

## Variable number of *ascents*

We can generalize the number of ascents, by generalizing for example the `get_descendants` function:

> ```
> def get_descendants(*klass):
>     gen = { *klass }
>     desc = set()
>     while gen:
>         gen = { skls for kls in gen for skls in kls.__subclasses__() }
>         desc.update(gen)
>     return desc
> ```

Next we can simply call it with:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

def filter_qs():
    if not hasattr(filter_qs_registry, '_q'):
        models = get_descendants(Registry, OtherAbstractModel)
        pks = [v.pk for v in ContentType.objects.get_for_models(*models).values()]
        filter_qs_registry._q = Q(pk__in=pks)
    return filter_qs_registry._q
```

Comment: Just another small addition: How would I add another class to the `models` in `filter_qs` in addition to the descendants of `Registry`?

Comment: Cool. And a great improvement. However, what I mean was just add a specific other model -- say a `note`-- to the list. Not descendants of `Note`, just `Note` itself. I tried `models.update(Note)` but got `'ModelBase' object is not iterable`…

Comment: @Sardathrion: you can use `models.add(Note)`, `.update(..)` means that you pass an iterable (for example a `list`) to the function.