# Can I run code every time an abstract class is inherited?

Tags: python, django

I need to connect a [django signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders) for all classes which inherit from an abstract class. Is there a magic python method like `__on_inherit__` which would allow me to run the signal connection code every time my abstract class is inherited?

Update: Just for clarification I need to run the code on class evaluation once per class, NOT once per instance/object.

Comment: just to clarify, when you say 'inherited' you mean 'an object of a subclass is instantiated'?

Comment: No. I mean when the a class definition which inherits the ABC is evaluated. I only need to register the signal once per class, NOT PER OBJECT!

Comment: OK, important clarification, I hope someone has an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can implement a solution for this. First we can generate the set of subclasses of an abstract model, for example with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853645/67579):

> ```
> def get_descendants(klass):
>     gen = { klass }
>     desc = set()
>     while gen:
>         gen = { skls for kls in gen for skls in kls.__subclasses__() }
>         desc.update(gen)
>     return desc
> ```

Next we can iterate over that, and each time call a function, like:

```
for subclass in get_descendants(AbstractModel):
    # ... do something with that subclass
    pass
```

Where *`AbstactModel`* is the abstract model from which you want to derive the subclasses.

You should trigger the evaluation of this, when the apps are loaded, so for example in the [**`ready()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) of an `AppConfig`.

It is very uncommon, especially for models to later make a new subclass. For models that would be very uncommon, and not a good idea anyway, since that would likely not work when you want to make migrations.

**Example**: adding a signal to each subclass

We can for example add a signal to each subclass of the *`AbstractModel`*, by first defining a signal handler:

```
def test_signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('{} is saved'.format(instance))
```

and then we can connect it with every subclass:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

for subclass in get_descendants(AbstractModel):
    post_save.connect(test_signal, sender=subclass)
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes indeed, there's the [`__init_subclass__`][1] hook, which is fired everytime a class is subclassed.

It'll be called with the first argument `cls` as the *new* subclass (not the original parent class).
As it's stated in the docs, you can even pass arbitrary arguments to the hook from the child classes.

Hope this helps you.

**Edit**: This was added via PEP 487 [2] in Python version 3.6. In earlier python versions this method is not called.

[1] [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**init_subclass**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__)

[2] https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/

Comment: [I tried this now in the REPL](https://gist.github.com/timthelion/bcd1d7ec45a5311b921eca37660feee1) and this appears to apply to every object creation. Which is not what I needed. How does this even differ from `__new__`?

Comment: What you're seeing in the instance creation it's the output of the REPL, not your print, [look at this other session](https://gist.github.com/Terseus/66ba75e8938f5738a6461a442ef2ccd6).
Also, remember you must call `super().__init_subclass__() or it will not work as expected.

Comment: Aha, I was confused by that output, you're right. But it doesn't  depend on the `super()` call. It does, however [depend on python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/) and I was running on 3.5. [Here you can see it working](https://gist.github.com/timthelion/520c9122dc563e76ab58e0830e309271) without the `super` in 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

For python >= 3.6, there's the `__init__subclass__` ok already mentionned by Terseus.

For older python verions, the canonical way to hook into class creation (I mean "creation of a new class object") is to use a custom metaclass and override either the `__new__` or `__init__` method (this is widely documented so I won't post an example).